# Filtering dates from different columns depending on conditions

Tags: r, conditional-statements, dplyr

An example of my dataset:

```
library('lubridate')
id<-c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
admidate<-c(dmy('01/01/2010', '01/01/2011', '01/02/2010', '01/02/2011', '01/01/2012', '01/01/2010', '01/03/2010', '01/03/2011'))
disdate<-c(dmy('15/01/2010', '15/01/2011', '15/02/2010', '15/02/2011', '15/02/2012', '15/01/2010', '15/03/2010', '15/03/2011'))
first_adm<-c(1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0)
last_adm<-c(0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1)
intervention<-c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
df<-data.frame(id, admidate, disdate, first_adm, last_adm, intervention)
```

For each `id`, I want to get a column of dates where:

1. If `intervention == 1`, time difference between `admidate` for this row and `last_adm==1` is returned.
2. If `intervention == 0`, time difference between `admidate` when `first_adm==1` for that `id` and `last_adm==1` for that `id` is returned.

Each `id` has only one `first_adm` and only one `last_adm`.

The purpose is to get follow times to compare between the two groups. For one it starts when they had an 'intervention'. For others who did not have intervention, it starts at first contact.

The `df` finally would look something like this:

> ```
>  id   admidate    disdate  first_adm last_adm   intervention fu_time
>   1 2010-01-01 2010-01-15         1        0            1     -
>   1 2011-01-01 2011-01-15         0        1            0     365
>   2 2010-02-01 2010-02-15         1        0            0     -
>   2 2011-01-01 2011-02-15         0        0            1     -
>   2 2012-01-01 2012-02-15         0        1            0     365
>   3 2010-01-01 2010-01-15         1        0            0     -
>   3 2010-03-01 2010-03-15         0        0            0     -
>   3 2011-03-01 2011-03-15         0        1            0     431
> ```

Comment: A little confused on what you are looking for. Perhaps adding a data frame with the desired output would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I think this might be a bit better. Do advise if I need to modify this further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would try with my preferred tool.

#### `data.table` version

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, {
  fa <- first(admidate[first_adm == 1])
  la <- last(admidate[last_adm == 1]) 
  fi <- first(admidate[intervention == 1])
  ai <- any(intervention == 1)
  .(fu_time = la - if (ai) pmax(fa, fi) else fa)
}, by = id]
```

which simply returns the result of each `id`

> ```
>    id  fu_time
> 1:  1 365 days
> 2:  2 334 days
> 3:  3 424 days
> ```

Note that we still use `first()` and `last()` here as we are aggregating by `id` although the OP has assured that each `id` has only one `first_adm` and only one `last_adm`.

However the OP wants to have the original `df` updated. With `data.table`, we can append a new column where each row contains the result for the respective group:

```
setDT(df)[, fu_time := {
  fa <- first(admidate[first_adm == 1])
  la <- last(admidate[last_adm == 1]) 
  fi <- first(admidate[intervention == 1])
  ai <- any(intervention == 1)
  la - if (ai) pmax(fa, fi) else fa
}, by = id]
```

Now, the original `df` has been updated:

```
df[]
```

> ```
>    id   admidate    disdate first_adm last_adm intervention  fu_time
> 1:  1 2010-01-01 2010-01-15         1        0            1 365 days
> 2:  1 2011-01-01 2011-01-15         0        1            0 365 days
> 3:  2 2010-02-01 2010-02-15         1        0            0 334 days
> 4:  2 2011-02-01 2011-02-15         0        0            1 334 days
> 5:  2 2012-01-01 2012-02-15         0        1            0 334 days
> 6:  3 2010-01-01 2010-01-15         1        0            0 424 days
> 7:  3 2010-03-01 2010-03-15         0        0            0 424 days
> 8:  3 2011-03-01 2011-03-15         0        1            0 424 days
> ```

If only the last row is to contain the result for each `id` and if we want to fully simulate OP's expected result:

```
setDT(df)[, fu_time := {
  fa <- first(admidate[first_adm == 1])
  la <- last(admidate[last_adm == 1]) 
  fi <- first(admidate[intervention == 1])
  ai <- any(intervention == 1)
  replace(rep("-", .N), .N, la - if (ai) pmax(fa, fi) else fa)
}, by = id]
df[]
```

> ```
>    id   admidate    disdate first_adm last_adm intervention fu_time
> 1:  1 2010-01-01 2010-01-15         1        0            1       -
> 2:  1 2011-01-01 2011-01-15         0        1            0     365
> 3:  2 2010-02-01 2010-02-15         1        0            0       -
> 4:  2 2011-02-01 2011-02-15         0        0            1       -
> 5:  2 2012-01-01 2012-02-15         0        1            0     334
> 6:  3 2010-01-01 2010-01-15         1        0            0       -
> 7:  3 2010-03-01 2010-03-15         0        0            0       -
> 8:  3 2011-03-01 2011-03-15         0        1            0     424
> ```

#### `dplyr` version

As the OP has tagged the question with *mutate* I suppose the OP might prefer a `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(
    fu_time = last(admidate[last_adm == 1]) - 
      if (any(intervention == 1))
        pmax(first(admidate[first_adm == 1]), first(admidate[intervention == 1]))
    else first(admidate[first_adm == 1])
  ) %>% 
  inner_join(df, .)
```

> ```
>   id   admidate    disdate first_adm last_adm intervention  fu_time
> 1  1 2010-01-01 2010-01-15         1        0            1 365 days
> 2  1 2011-01-01 2011-01-15         0        1            0 365 days
> 3  2 2010-02-01 2010-02-15         1        0            0 334 days
> 4  2 2011-02-01 2011-02-15         0        0            1 334 days
> 5  2 2012-01-01 2012-02-15         0        1            0 334 days
> 6  3 2010-01-01 2010-01-15         1        0            0 424 days
> 7  3 2010-03-01 2010-03-15         0        0            0 424 days
> 8  3 2011-03-01 2011-03-15         0        1            0 424 days
> ```

Note that this will not update `df` but creates a new object.

#### Caveat

It is implicitely assumed that the dataset is already ordered by ascending `admidate` within each `id` group.